# Count and display entries with a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop, while-loop

I have menu that displays entries using php and mysql. What I'm trying to do is to get a list of products that equal clothing for example then shoes and so on. Theirs about 4 main types, this value can't be changed.

So:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE type = 'Clothing'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Instead of looping through I'll just repeat the process 4 times.
After this I want to display each main category and sub category for each type of clothing with the products table, so that it displays like this.

Clothing

Main Category 1
(1)Sub 1
(35)Sub 2
(4)Sub 3

Main Category 2
(1)Sub 1
(35)Sub 2
(4)Sub 3

Shoes

Main Category 1
(1)Sub 1
(35)Sub 2
(4)Sub 3

Main Category 2
(1)Sub 1
(35)Sub 2
(4)Sub 3

And so on
I get a list of each main catogroy in the DB form a different table and loop through

```
$get_cats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM main_cats")or die(mysql_error());
    //loop through each 
while($main_cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_cats)){
    //count main cat in products
    $check = mysql_real_escape_string($main_cat['cat']);
        $p_main_count =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE cats = '$check' ORDER BY cats")or die(mysql_error());
//this would get an array of each product that has that main category
}
```

This looks all well and good but I can't think of a way how to display the data in the format I need it.
The products table has 3 main columns for this:

1. type
2. cats (main category)
3. sub cats (contains string 1,2,4 of multiple sub categorys)

Is there a way selecting and groups each main category and then displaying and counting the sub category's for each main category.

Answer (score 1):

W3Schools has a really good tutorial for counting and displaying MySql Database entries. Here's a snippet of how you could try to display the Data in a table.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM main_cats");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo $row['type'] . " " . $row['cats'] . " " . $row['subcats'];
  echo "<br>";
  }
?>
```

Lets say row 1 has the data Type: 1 Cats: 2 SubCats: 3

and row 2 has the data Type:2 Cats: 4 SubCats: 6


This would output the data like this


1 2 3

2 4 6

You can easily use the tables from HTML to make this look alot nicer.

```
echo "<table border="1">";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo "<tr><td>" . $row['type'] . "</td><td> " . $row['cats'] . "</td><td> " . $row['subcats'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

This would output in the same order but in a table.

Hope this helps. Also if you want any good references http://w3schools.com is a very good website.